# Watermark images, but only orginal images (the large ones)

Tags: product-attribute, image, watermark

I would like to protect my images with the watermark. I know there is the functionality in Magento for the watermark. My web site has functionality where visitors are able to click on base image and then load larger size of that image (lightbox), and that is the image that I want to protect. When I use **Thumbnail Watermark** in Magento, all images are watermarked, which is not what I would like to accomplished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible out-of-the-box.

You can see in `\Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image::init` how the watermarks work. So what you need to do is call the methods at the place where you want the watermark.

Something like:

```
$this->helper('catalog/image')
->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135)
->setWatermark(<expects a path I think>)
->setWatermarkImageOpacity(<0-100>)
->setWatermarkPosition(<Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Source_Watermark_Position>)
->setWatermarkSize(WxH);
```